# Prove that the linear transformation cannot be onto

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> Let $\newcommand{\x}{\boldsymbol{x}} T(\x)=A\x$ be a linear transformation that maps $\Bbb{R}^n$ into $\Bbb{R}^m$, and assume that $m>n$. Prove that $T(\x)$ can not possibly be onto.

**Proof:** Suppose $m>n$, and that $T(\x)=A\x$ is a linear transformation that maps $\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^m$. Since $m>n$, we see that $A\x$ has more equations than variables, thus there will not be a pivot in every row, by definition of an onto transformation, hence $T(\x)$ cannot possibly be onto. ∎

Considering this is for an elementary linear algebra course, how was this proof?

Comment: I really depends on what you have developed in the course already. How about dimension, row space, column space etc? Do you have that already?

Comment: I’ve made several formatting revisions. Please review them and try to emulate them in the future. Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr), and you’ll want to use this both to create your own math-style text and to transcribe images into block quotes so that they can be more easily read.